# T-SQL read from JSON Array

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, parsing, sql-server-2016

I have the following `JSON`

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max) = '
{
  "source": "one",
  "dataSetId":"a3d5-14fda14",
  "data": [
    {
      "FieldId": 10
    }
  ]
}
'
```

and need to parse the values to the table.

I have tried:

```
-- meta
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH ( source NVARCHAR(20)
        ,dataSetId NVARCHAR(50)
        ,FieldId INT '$.data.FieldId'
)

-- array
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data')
  WITH ( source NVARCHAR(20)
        ,dataSetId NVARCHAR(50)
        ,FieldId int '$.FieldId'
)
```

It works to get `source` and `dataSetId` columns or to get `FieldId` column, but I am still unable to merge both solution, to parse both non-array and array data.

The `SELECT` should return all the data in one query.

Comment: If you tried then What sql error you getting.

Comment: Yes, I did. You can see the queries in the question. There's no error. .. it works, but does not return all the data from JSON in one query.

Comment: Should you try with by defining a temp table and store your result into temp table i.e #myResultTable and pass it to OPENJSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many  solutions for this question. one of them is....

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max) = '
 {
   "source": "one",
   "dataSetId":"a3d5-14fda14",
   "data": [
    {
      "FieldId": 10
    }
  ]
}'

SELECT  A.* , B.*  
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
  WITH ( source NVARCHAR(20)
        ,dataSetId NVARCHAR(50)) A ,  
 OPENJSON(@json, '$.data') 
  WITH (  FieldId int '$.FieldId') B
```